# Is there some geometrical intuition behind separable and or purely inseparable extensions?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I know that transcendence degree expresses in language of algebraic geometry the dimension of the variety over the base field, but I do not know any geometric analogue for separable extensions or purely inseparable ones.

Is there such a geometric characterization? Can these notions give you important geometric information?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes.

If $k$ is a field, the [unramified](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramification) $k$-schemes are precisely the finite disjoint unions of spectra of finite separable field extensions of $k$ (A proof can be found in any book on algebraic geometry). In particular, a $k$-algebra which is a domain is unramified if and only if it *is* a finite separable field extension.

A field extension is purely inseparable if and only if the corresponding morphism of schemes is [radicial](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radicial_morphism). This is a geometric version of the statement that a homomorphism of fields is an epimorphism in the category of fields if and only if it is purely inseparable (and algebraic).

Comment: Ok, thanks, I'll look these up!